# LINQ Sum Query on a Child element

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, sum, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate the invoices in a month for my application. There are two objects; an `Invoice` object, and an `InvoiceDetails` object. The `Invoice` object contains particulars regarding the invoice (date, customer, etc), while the `InvoiceDetails` object contains the line items for each invoice (quantity, price, tax, etc). I want to calculate the revenue for each month based on the money coming in from invoices. I can aggregate the invoices by date using the `GroupBy` method, however I can't seem to add the line items in the `InvoiceDetails` which would give me the total revenue for the month. The objects are listed below.

Invoice class:

```
Public Class Invoice

    Public Property InvoiceID As Integer
    Public Property InvoiceDate As Date
    Public Property DueDate As Date
    Public Property Details As List(Of InvoiceDetail)
    Public Property Client As Client
    Public Property ClientID As Integer

End Class
```

InvoiceDetails class:

```
Public Class InvoiceDetail

    Public Property InvoiceDetailID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property UnitPrice As Decimal
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Public Property Subtotal As Decimal
    Public Property Tax As Decimal
    Public Property Total As Decimal
    Public Property Invoice As Invoice

End Class
```

My current LINQ query is as follows:

```
Public Function GetRevenueByMonth(Year As Integer, Month As Integer) As DataSourceResult

    Dim StartDate As New Date(Year, Month, 1)
    Dim EndDate As Date = StartDate.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)

    Dim Revenue = _db.Invoices.Include(Function(i) i.InvoiceDetails
        .Select(Function(invd) invd.Total))
        .Where(Function(i) i.InvoiceDate >= StartDate And i.InvoiceDate <= EndDate)
        .GroupBy(Function(i) i.InvoiceDate.Date)
        .Select(Function(r) New With {
            .Date = r.Key, .Revenue = r.Sum(Function(invd) invd.Total)
        })

End Function
```

The function looks fine until the second last line. I get the error of 'Total' is not a member of 'InvoiceDetail'. I would expect that `invd` would reference the child element, but instead it's referencing the parent element. How can I make this LINQ query work?

Comment: Just a note: if you didn't `.AddSeconds(-1)` then you could use `i.InvoiceDate < EndDate` and not have to worry about fractions of a second. Unless an invoice timed at 23:59:59.95 should be included in the next day.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you want to get the sum of the invoices for a particular year and month? How is `Invoice` connected to `InvoiceDetails`? - the declarations of `Invoice` and `InvoiceDetails` might help us more than a verbal description.

Comment: `InvoiceDetails` is a collection of child objects of `Invoice`. The invoice has a collection of line items which is what `InvoiceDetails` is. Each line item has an item description, along with the quantity and price. I want to sum up the price of each line item for the month.

Comment: Sorry, but without the verbatim code declarations it is not easy to understand *precisely* what you mean. If you write the code in the form `_db.Invoices.Select(Function(inv As Invoice) inv.InvoiceDate >= startDate AndAlso inv.InvoiceDate < endDate).Sum(Function(i As Invoice)...` with the `As` terms, perhaps it would help see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've altered the code to include the declarations of the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
 Dim Revenue = _db.InvoicesDetails
        .Where(Function(i) i.Invoice.InvoiceDate >= StartDate And i.Invoice.InvoiceDate <= EndDate)
        .GroupBy(Function(i) i.Invoice.InvoiceDate.Date)
        .Select(Function(r) New With {
            .Date = r.Key, .Revenue = r.Sum(Function(invd) invd.Total)
        })
```

Hope this will help you